# TS : inherited interfaces raise type error in function parameters

Tags: typescript

In this code sample, B extends A so a B-value can go into a A-variable.
But, for some reason I don't understand, this is not true for function parameters :

```ts
interface A { foo: string };
interface B extends A { bar: string };

let a: A = {foo: "foo"};
let b: B = {foo: "foo", bar: "bar"};

a = b; // OK
    
type AFUNC = (a: A) => true;
type BFUNC = (b: B) => true;
    
let aGetter: AFUNC = a => true;
let bGetter: BFUNC = b => true;
    
aGetter = bGetter; // Error :
    // Type 'BFUNC' is not assignable to type 'AFUNC'.
    //   Types of parameters 'b' and 'a' are incompatible.
    //     Property 'bar' is missing in type 'A' but required in type 'B'.ts(2322)
```

Why does TS assumes `BFUNC = b => true` can't be assigned to `AFUNC = a => true` ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [*function type parameter positions are checked contravariantly*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html), you can assign the other way around i.e. `bGetter = aGetter` works but not `aGetter = bGetter`. See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7JgexwLmQGcwpQBzZAXwG4AoUSWRFAIWQgA9IQATItJmQAjOFEIkyISrTp0ANhDDI4hdAF5MuAsgBE23bMXLhhdpozbC+vLoA0IsddFRD9OnGSbhNZAHo-ZAB5AGk6ZAjkOjAATwAHFFQAMQBVADkAYS9kAApVNABKLwA+ZFIAVwh6WITkVlTM7JzTOqL1Uoqq8MiFJRUAcSUmNQaszU92sqhK+mMRQbBhutHs4RKpme6IumEFpmy4Peg6AIGh6FWjqBogA).

Comment: Okay I see.
I didn't figure why it this behave like that until i read this well-explained article :
https://medium.com/@michalskoczylas/covariance-contravariance-and-a-little-bit-of-typescript-2e61f41f6f68